# Other than binary search, are there other algorithms that have a running time of O(log n)?

Tags: algorithm, runtime, big-o

Understanding the runtime of an algorithm has been the achilles heel in my understanding of computer science principles. Binary search keeps coming up as the prevailing example of logarithmic runtime. Common analogies include the dictionary and phone book examples. Are there other common or well-known examples (to non-beginners) that have a running time of O(log n)?

Comment: There could be infinite algorithms with O(logN) complexity, like searching/inserting in a balanced BST

Comment: naive integer version of `log2` (highest set binary bit search with bitshifting)

Answer (score 0):

[Ancient Egyptian
multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Egyptian_multiplication)
takes logarithmic time (on the unit-cost RAM). Ditto [exponentiation by
squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring)
(they’re very similar).

Also, operating on a tree of height h is often Θ(h), which is
logarithmic when h = Θ(log n). Binary search trees are uncomfortably
close to binary search, perhaps, but you also see log-height trees in
priority queue algorithms.